# Why do i receive a NullPointerExeption in my JFrame while using my array "messwerte"

Tags: java, arrays, jframe

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Messreihe extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField tfAnzahlMesswerte;
    private JTextField tfMesswert;
    private JTextField tfMesswertBearbeiten;
    private JTextField tfNeuerWert;
    private JLabel lblMesswert;
    private JButton btnMesswert;
    private int n;
    private int anzahl;
    double[] messwerte;
    

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            Messreihe frame = new Messreihe();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
    }

    public Messreihe() {
        setTitle("Messreihe");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 357);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblAnzahlMesswerte = new JLabel("Wieviele Messwerte sollen eingegeben werden?");
    lblAnzahlMesswerte.setBounds(10, 11, 282, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblAnzahlMesswerte);
    
    tfAnzahlMesswerte = new JTextField(); // textfield to input number of measured values
    tfAnzahlMesswerte.setBounds(302, 8, 54, 20);
    contentPane.add(tfAnzahlMesswerte);
    tfAnzahlMesswerte.setColumns(10);
    
    JButton btnAnzahlMesswerte = new JButton("OK"); //count of my measured values
    btnAnzahlMesswerte.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            anzahl = Integer.parseInt(tfAnzahlMesswerte.getText());
            lblAnzahlMesswerte.setVisible(false);
            btnAnzahlMesswerte.setVisible(false);
            tfAnzahlMesswerte.setVisible(false);
            messwerte = new double[anzahl];
            n++;
            lblMesswert.setVisible(true);
                    lblMesswert.setText(n + ". Messwert:");
            btnMesswert.setVisible(true);
            tfMesswert.setVisible(true);
                        
        }
    });
    btnAnzahlMesswerte.setBounds(366, 7, 62, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnAnzahlMesswerte);
    
    JLabel lblMesswert = new JLabel("Messwert:");
    lblMesswert.setVisible(false);
    lblMesswert.setBounds(10, 36, 75, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblMesswert);
    
    tfMesswert = new JTextField();
    tfMesswert.setVisible(false);
    tfMesswert.setBounds(10, 53, 96, 20);
    contentPane.add(tfMesswert);
    tfMesswert.setColumns(10);
    
    JButton btnMesswert = new JButton("OK");
    btnMesswert.setVisible(false);
    btnMesswert.setBounds(116, 52, 62, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnMesswert);
    

    JLabel lblMittelwert = new JLabel("Mittelwert"); //average
    lblMittelwert.setBounds(10, 294, 96, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblMittelwert);
    }
}
```

i wanted to create an array to save measured values, and calculate their average.
In the button "Anzahl Messwerte" i tried defining the length of the array, but everytime i use the button i get a NullPointerExeption.

Im new to java, and wanted to ask how to correct my code.
Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the Exception and the stacktrace. It tells you exactly which line the Exception is being thrown from, also newer version of java tells you which variable or expression is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, that you declare the components both as fields and local variables. You should reference them, not created locally too.
Like this:

```
lblMesswert = new JLabel("Messwert:");
```

and not:

```
JLabel lblMesswert = new JLabel("Messwert:");
```